# JReport :Subreport query should filter based on sublink?

Tags: subreport

I am trying to create a report with subreport in it but I am getting error while executing sbreport query.

The main table shows the details of employee and subquery shows the detail of leaves for each month for each employee.

I have created a subquery where I am selecting all details from the table.

What my issue is:

When I am creating a subquery it should filter based on the sublink.

For example each row in the main report will represent an employee. If the sublink between main report and subreport is employee id, then the subquery should filter the detail based on the sublink.

i.e. if the subquery is

```
"select employee_id, noOfLeaves from Employee_Detail"
```

then while executing it should execute like

```
select employee_id, noOfLeaves from Employee_Detail where employee_id = 151 (where employee_id = 151 is the row from the main report)
```

Is there any setting in JDesigner where I can make the changes to get this.

I am using Version 10 JERntServer and JDesigner.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to right click on the subreport or embedded component and select Format Subreport or Link Properties and in the Field tab select the BandedObject in the Component edit box then select Field (Primary) = Field (Subreport) with employee_id of both reports.  Be sure both reports contain employee_id.